# SQL Filter the output based on decimal format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008, and I have an output like this:

```
OrderNo        Amount1       Amount2       Amount3      Amount4 
----------------------------------------------------------------
20001        473.050000     24.080000    528.050000    63.040000
20002        473.052854     24.081236    528.054536    63.044256
20003        563.960000     35.220000    679.050000    95.780000
20004        563.963566     35.223569    679.052122    95.784569
20005        897.050000     96.960000    346.120000    33.940000
20006        897.052365     96.964568    346.121897    33.944544
20007        268.550000     19.660000    986.330000    81.550000
20007        268.551778     19.663655    986.333566    81.553365
```

How can I filter the output and remove the number with decimal format like "123.456789" and the remaining will be "123.450000" as shown below:

```
OrderNo        Amount1       Amount2       Amount3      Amount4 
----------------------------------------------------------------
20001        473.050000     24.080000    528.050000    63.040000
20003        563.960000     35.220000    679.050000    95.780000
20005        897.050000     96.960000    346.120000    33.940000
20007        268.550000     19.660000    986.330000    81.550000
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if a number has more than two non-zero digits then:

```
WHERE ROUND(Amount1,2) = Amount1
```

Use this accordingly for other fields.

Comment: Hi, the output is given, so I only need is to filter the output as specified.